# Is there a public specification of WebGL anywhere?

Tags: javascript, firefox, opengl-es, webkit, webgl

It seems the Khronos group is fairly closed when it comes to releasing early specs for WebGL to the public.

Does anyone know of a resource to keep up to date on API changes?

The only thing I can seem to find, short of doing a checkout of Firefox or WebKit sources, is a page from 2007 on Vladimir Vukićević's blog with a small list of OpenGL ES -> WebGL functions.

**[edit: I made this post before the spec was available online. See the answer below for a link.]**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[edit: There is now a public draft available: http://www.khronos.org/webgl/ ]

Nope -- khronos group tends to publish specs much later in the dev process than W3C or WHATWG, i'd suggest looking at the webkit webgl tests as i believe webkit's implementation currently matches the spec more closely, but neither is perfect (yet) :-(